# Concatenating the array remainder

Tags: android, arrays

I have an array like

```
Hello
There
How
Are
You
```

from a string s, received by split(" "). My goal is to address the first two separately as in array[0] and array[1], but the rest together as in "How Are You". The rest can be more or less than three words.

So far I did

```
rest = s.replace(array[0]+" "+array[1]+ " ","");
```

Which approach is more elegant?

Something like `array[2 to array.length-1]` or `array[2;end;" "]`where " " is the separator.

Comment: Define elegant ?

Comment: @WilomGfx something like `array[2 to array.length-1]` or `array[2;end;" "]`where " " is the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already checked Android's `TextUtils.join`?
You could fix the 2 first elements of the array using `String.format` and then concatenate with other elements using `TextUtils.join`.

So it would be:

```
String start = String.format("%s %s!", array[0], array[1]);
```

Then the rest of the text would be:

```
String rest = TextUtils.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, array.length));
```

And for the whole text, you'd just concatenate them:

```
String result = new StringBuilder(start).append(rest);
```

Of course you'll want to put other characters between the words, like commas or something.

And just remebering that in this example we're using `Arrays`, `TextUtils` and `StringBuilder`, so you'll have to import them.